# Logoff Disconnected user sessions based on IDLE time

Tags: powershell, multi-user, usersession, disconnected-session

I have written a PS script to find any user who has a disconnected RDP session on remote servers and I got help from user @Theo to get it finished.

Now add on to my script, I want to Log off the disconnected users if the IDLE time is more than 1 day.

This will help us a lot for me to achieve the things

**CODE**

```
## Clear Host Console
Clear-Host

## Define Variable for Server Count
$z = 0

##Set Default Script Location
Set-Location $PSScriptRoot

## Provide List of Servers to Check for the Disconnected user session
$Servers = Get-Content ".\Servers\DA_Servers.txt"

## Get Servers Count
$count = $Servers.count 

## Define Date for the Out file
$dt = Get-Date -Format yyyyMMdd
$Date = Get-Date

## Define Path for the Out File
$exportFile = ".\Out\RDP_DisConnected_Users.csv"

## Create a Function to list all user sessions from Remote Servers
function Get-RemoteUsers {

## Loop through each server to find the User session    
foreach ($Computer in $Servers) {

#initiate counter for showing progress
$z = $z + 1

# Start writing progress 
Write-Progress -Activity "Processing Server: $z out of $count servers." -Status " Progress" -PercentComplete ($z/$Servers.count*100)

$obj = "" | Select-Object @{Name = 'ServerName'; Expression = {$Computer}}, UserName, ID, State, IdleTime, LogonTime
    
  try {
         quser /server:$Computer 2>&1 | Select-Object -Skip 1 | ForEach-Object {
         $items = $_.Trim() -split '\s{2,}'
         $obj.UserName     = $items[0]
                 
# If session is disconnected different fields will be selected
    if ($items[2] -like 'Disc*') 
    {
         $obj.Id          = $items[1]
         $obj.State       = $items[2]
         $obj.IdleTime    = $items[3]
         $obj.LogonTime   = $items[4..($items.GetUpperBound(0))] -join ' ' 
     }
    else {
          $obj.Id          = $items[1]
          $obj.State       = $items[2]
          $obj.IdleTime    = $items[3]
          $obj.LogonTime   = $items[4] 
         }

# reformat the IdleTime property
          $obj.IdleTime = '{0} days, {1} hours, {2} minutes' -f ([int[]]([regex]'^(?:(\d+)\+)?(\d+):(\d+)').Match($obj.IdleTime).Groups[1..3].Value | ForEach-Object { $_ })
        # output the object
          $obj
      }
   } 
  catch {
            #$obj.Error = $_.Exception.Message
            #$obj
        }
    }
}

## Filter the results to find out the disconnected users
$allRemoteUsers = Get-RemoteUsers  $Servers
$disconnectedUsers = $allRemoteUsers | Where-Object {$_.State -like 'disc*' }
if (@($disconnectedUsers).Count) {
    #output on screen
    $disconnectedUsers | Format-Table -AutoSize
    # output to Csv
    $disconnectedUsers | Export-Csv "$exportFile" -NoTypeInformation
}
else {
    Write-Host "No disconnected users found" -BackgroundColor Red
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You then need to reverse the `.IdleTime` property back to integer numbers to determine if the user has been idle for more than 1 day:

```
foreach ($item in $disconnectedUsers) {
    # read back the values for Days, Hours and Minutes from the formatted string
    $d, $h, $m = [int[]]([regex]'(\d+) days, (\d+) hours, (\d+) minutes').Match($item.IdleTime).Groups[1..3].Value
    if ($d -gt 1 -or ($d -eq 1 -and ($h -gt 0 -or $m -gt 0))) {
        # been idle for more than 1 day, so logoff the user here
        Write-Host "Logging off $($item.UserName) from computer $($item.ServerName).."
        logoff $item.Id /SERVER:$($item.ServerName)
        # or use: rwinsta $item.Id /SERVER:$($item.ServerName)
    }
}
```

---

To add that to your existing code, just update the final `if(..){..} else{..}` to include that:

```
if (@($disconnectedUsers).Count) {
    #output on screen
    $disconnectedUsers | Format-Table -AutoSize
    # output to Csv
    $disconnectedUsers | Export-Csv "$exportFile" -NoTypeInformation

    # next, loop through the disconnected user connections and test if there are idle connections older than 1 day
    # if so then log them off
    foreach ($item in $disconnectedUsers) {
        # read back the values for Days, Hours and Minutes from the formatted string
        $d, $h, $m = [int[]]([regex]'(\d+) days, (\d+) hours, (\d+) minutes').Match($item.IdleTime).Groups[1..3].Value
        if ($d -gt 1 -or ($d -eq 1 -and ($h -gt 0 -or $m -gt 0))) {
            # been idle for more than 1 day, so logoff the user here
            Write-Host "Logging off $($item.UserName) from computer $($item.ServerName).."
            logoff $item.Id /SERVER:$($item.ServerName)
            # or use: rwinsta $item.Id /SERVER:$($item.ServerName)
        }
    }
}
else {
    Write-Host "No disconnected users found" -BackgroundColor Red
}
```

Comment: How can we modify the script like if the user IDLE time is more than 1 day then we need to logoff that user

Comment: @nikonD3400 You can simply add it in the `if (@($disconnectedUsers).Count) {..}` block. Please see my edit